# LIKE pattern matching on AS400

Tags: sql, db2-400

I have a table with one column(ID), values are in the format of 
'123-456-7890'.Now I need to fetch all the rows from the table whose ID values are of the  same format.
I tried to query as

```
Select * 
  from file 
  where ID like ('%___-___-____%')
```

But no records were found.
Kindly let me know how to accomplish this.
Thanks

Comment: If all values have the given format, you shouldn't need `LIKE` at all.  This is a similar format to a US phone number (which you shouldn't be storing formatted).  What happens if you ask for just one of the dashes (ie, something akin to `LIKE '___-%'`)?  If that's the only thing in your data, you shouldn't need the `%` operator.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need the parentheses.

Try using

```
where ID like '___-___-____'
```

Comment: He might not need them, but I'm fairly certain they aren't going to change his results.  I'm more curious about the fact that you removed the `%` operator.

Comment: I agree. When I wrote the answer, I dont think I had formatted his  code yet.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the field data type?
You can have a numeric field shown with an edition pattern, and although your actual field value is 1234567890, you see it formatted as 123-456-7890.
For a char/varchar your sentence should work, for a numeric won't do.
So, is your field type char, varchar, numeric, decimal...?
Please post your comments.

Comment: The so-called "edition pattern" would likely be an referred to as an Edit Word [aka EdtWrd; perhaps Edit Mask or EdtMsk might also be used] that describes the formatting for the numeric values.  This *answer* seems most likely to be appropriate; i.e. the user was seeing the effect of implicit cast of the numeric to character, such that the character comparison\predicate was not diagnosed as an error.